# Hello World Plugin - Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

I'm following this guide :https://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/plugins/hello-world-with-android-plugin/#Generating android plugin
but i'm bit confused  at this step:

[image]
  contains package.json file  PluginConfig.JSON data or are in mytest folder two files? 
In PluginConfig.JSON file :
`{“classes”:[“com.example.mervebicakci.helloworld.HelloNotifier”]}` and
in package.json file:

```
{
    "name" : "helloPlugin",
    "version" : "1.0.0",
    "description" : "Smartface Hello Plugin",
    "keywords" : [
        "Smartface",
        "Hello",
        "Plugin"
    ],
    "author" : "Smartface Inc.",
    "license" : "ISC",
    "OS" : "Android",
    "cpu" : ["arm", "x86"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have these two separated files in the folder where you will build the apk.

Hope that answers your question, because it's not very clear what you wanna know and what is your problem. :)